# how to send email on mutt

Tags: linux, email, exit, mutt

I'm starting in programming and i'm supposed to send my code by email using a the mutt command. So I write:

```
mutt -s "email subject" -a attached_file.txt -- profesor@gmail.com
```

Then it confirms me the professor email, I press enter. It confirms the email subject, I press enter a second time. But then it opens a text editor within linux for the email text content I and can't manage to continue that part. Which keys do I have to press to finish to send the email?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I tried pressing `Esc`, then `:x` or `:q` as in `vim`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is your linux? Which text editor is open, is there any indication of its name (or check output of `echo $EDITOR`/`ls -l /etc/alternatives/editor`, or `pstree` in other console). Different editors will require different keys to exit. And this is how to change default editor in debian/ubuntu: https://superuser.com/a/168710 (about editor setting in mutt - http://mutt.postle.net/editing/ and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mutt#)

Comment: Okay so I'm using mobaXterm as terminal but I figured out that my default text editor is emacs. Any idea on how to finish to send the email?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the email with `y`. Also there is a [key-binding cheat-sheet](http://www.ucolick.org/~lharden/muttchart.html)

Comment: Will `y` work in context of External Text Editor which is Emacs for case of Fabian Vllb's linux? (Can you add basic save & exit commands of most popular editors to the answer?)